# Pygame: Initial menu leading up to game loop

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a version of [this game](http://agar.io), and I'm trying to make the starting menu like so:
[image: starting menu]

My plan is to start by doing `surface.fill(overlaycolor)` then blitting this image onto the screen. That will be in one while loop. Afterwards, after the users wants to play (save that for another question) then we will enter into another while loop.

I tried doing that, but it just gives me a black screen.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
width = 800
height = 600
thesurface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('')

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
menu1 = pygame.image.load("menu1.png")

basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 36)

# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
overlay = (121, 126, 128)
playercolor = BLUE
# set up the player and food data structure
foodCounter = 0
NEWFOOD = 20
FOODSIZE = 10
splitting = False
player = pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, (60, 250), 40)

foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))

# set up movement variables
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 10
size = 10
score = size
gameisplaying = False
while True:
    thesurface.fill(overlay)
    thesurface.blit(menu1, (400,400))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            gameisplaying = True
    break
# run the game loop
while gameisplaying:
    thesurface.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    # check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # change the keyboard variables
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
            if event.key == K_SPACE and size >= 32: # XXX if size and space set splitting to true
                splitting = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == ord('x'):
                player.top = random.randint(0, height - player.height)
                player.left = random.randint(0, width - player.width)
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0], event.pos[1], FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))



    foodCounter += 1
    if foodCounter >= NEWFOOD:
        # add new food
        foodCounter = 0
        foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, width - FOODSIZE), random.randint(0, height - FOODSIZE), FOODSIZE, FOODSIZE))
    if 100>score>50:
        MOVESPEED = 9
    elif 150>score>100:
        MOVESPEED = 8
    elif 250>score>150:
        MOVESPEED = 6
    elif 400>score>250:
        MOVESPEED = 5
    elif 600>score>400:
        MOVESPEED = 3
    elif 800>score>600:
        MOVESPEED = 2
    elif score>800:
        MOVESPEED = 1
    # move the player
    if moveDown and player.bottom < height:
        player.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < width:
        player.right += MOVESPEED

    # splitting
    if not splitting:
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor, player.center, size)
    else:
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx,player.centery),int(size/2))
        pygame.draw.circle(thesurface, playercolor,(player.centerx+size,player.centery+size),int(size/2))
    # check if the player has intersected with any food squares.
    for food in foods[:]:
        if player.colliderect(food):
            foods.remove(food)
            size+=1

    # draw the food
    for i in range(len(foods)):
        pygame.draw.rect(thesurface, GREEN, foods[i])

    printscore = basicFont.render("Score: %d" % size, True, (0,0,0))
    thesurface.blit(printscore, (10, 550))

    pygame.display.update()
    # draw the window onto the thesurface
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(80)
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
...
gameisplaying = False
while True:
    thesurface.fill(overlay)
    thesurface.blit(menu1, (400,400))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            gameisplaying = True
    break
# run the game loop
while gameisplaying:
   ...
```

First, you immediatly break the first `while` loop at the end of the first iteration. So you leave the loop without setting `gameisplaying` to `True`, which in turn means the second `while` loop never runs.

Second, you draw something on the screen in the first loop, but you never call `pygame.display.flip()` to make that changes actually visible.

---

Here's a little example I hacked together while I was bored. Note how the action goes on in the background while the game is in the `MENU` state, and you can switch to the `RUNNING` state by clicking with the mouse:

```
import pygame
import math
import random
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import cycle

def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def add(u, v):
    return [(a+b) for (a, b) in zip(u, v)]

def sub(u, v):
    return [(a-b) for (a, b) in zip(u, v)]

def dot(u, v):
    return sum((a*b) for a, b in zip(u, v))

def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [ v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v)) ]

def length(v):
  return math.sqrt(dot(v, v))

def angle(v1, v2):
  return math.acos(dot(v1, v2) / (length(v1) * length(v2)))

class Cell(object):

    id = 0

    def __init__(self, pos, color, speed, size, controller):
        self.x, self.y = pos
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.target_vector = [0, 0]
        self.controller = controller
        Cell.id += 1
        self.id = Cell.id

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    @property
    def int_pos(self):
        return [int(v) for v in self.pos]

    @property
    def int_size(self):
        return int(self.size)

    def update(self, surroundings):

        if self.size > 6:
            self.size *= 0.999 

        eatting = [c for c in surroundings if can_a_eat_b(self, c)]
        for c in eatting:
            self.size += int(c.size / 2.5)

        if self.speed == 0: return eatting
        self.target_vector = self.controller(self, surroundings)
        if length(self.target_vector ) < 1: return eatting
        move_vector = [c * self.speed for c in normalize(self.target_vector)]
        self.x, self.y = add(self.pos, move_vector)
        return eatting

    def draw(self, s):
        pygame.draw.circle(s, self.color, self.int_pos, self.int_size)
        if not str(self.id).startswith('Food'):
            s.blit(write(str(self.id)), add(self.int_pos, (5, 5)))

def can_a_eat_b(a, b):
    return a.id != b.id and a.size > b.size and length(sub(a.pos, b.pos)) <= a.size + b.size

def player_controller(cell, surroundings):
    return sub(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), cell.pos)

colors = [c for c in pygame.color.THECOLORS.values()]
def rand_color(): 
    return random.choice(colors)

def rand_pos(rect):
    return random.randint(0, rect.width), random.randint(0, rect.height)

def food_controller(cell, surroundings):
    return (0, 0)

def food_factory(rect):
    cell = Cell(rand_pos(rect), rand_color(), 0, 5, food_controller)
    cell.id = 'Food' + str(cell.id)
    return cell

def ai_controller(cell, surroundings):
    targets = [(c, length(sub(cell.pos, c.pos))) for c in surroundings if c.size < cell.size and cell.id != c.id]
    targets_sorted = sorted(targets, key=lambda i: i[1])

    if targets_sorted:
        return sub(targets_sorted[0][0].pos, cell.pos)

    return (0, 0)

def ai_factory(rect):
    return Cell(rand_pos(rect), rand_color(), 0.7, 6, ai_controller)

Info = namedtuple('Info', ['size', 'pos', 'id'])

MENU, RUNNING = 0, 1

font = None
def write(text):
    return font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))

def main():    
    state = MENU
    pygame.init()
    global font
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 17)
    s = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    s_rect = s.get_rect()
    c = pygame.time.Clock()
    CREATEFOOD = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    CREATEAI = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
    pygame.time.set_timer(CREATEFOOD, 1000)
    pygame.time.set_timer(CREATEAI, 3000)

    marquee = cycle(range(800))

    player = None
    for _ in range(10): pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(CREATEFOOD))
    for _ in range(4): pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(CREATEAI))

    actors = []

    while True:

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT: return
            if e.type == CREATEFOOD: actors.append(food_factory(s_rect))
            if e.type == CREATEAI: actors.append(ai_factory(s_rect))
            if state == MENU:
                if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: 
                    player = Cell((200, 200), rand_color(), 0.7, 6, player_controller)
                    actors.append(player)
                    player.id = 'Player'
                    state = RUNNING


        surroundings = [Info(c.size, c.int_pos, c.id) for c in actors]
        killed = []
        for ar in actors:
            for eaten in ar.update(surroundings):
                killed.append(eaten)

        actors = [a for a in actors if not a.id in [k.id for k in killed]]

        s.fill((255, 255, 255))

        for ar in actors:
            ar.draw(s)

        if state == MENU:
            s.blit(write('Click anywhere to start'), (next(marquee), 300))

        pygame.display.flip()
        c.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]
[image]

I hope you can take some inspiration.